# How can I put a line frame around an embedded video on Weebly?

Tags: html, video

I am embedding a video from my screencast.com account into my weebly website.

I am using the HTML appended at the bottom of this posting.

It is appearing with a thin border line on all sides except the right hand side.

You can see it here, its the second video down on the right hand side of this page:

http://www.themathstutor.ie/home-temp.html

I have tried making more physical space in the web page for it, but that does not seem to be the reason.

Can I put something in the HTML to put a thin line around the whole thing?

I have tried putting in different dimensions in the HTML, and sometimes I get the border on the RHS, but never all 4 at the same time.

Can someone advise please?

```
<!-- copy and paste. Modify height and width if desired. -->       
<object id="scPlayer"  width="320" height="180" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://content.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/scplayer.swf" >
    <param name="movie" value="http://content.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/scplayer.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="thumb=http://content.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/FirstFrame.jpg&containerwidth=320&containerheight=180&autohide=true&autostart=false&loop=false&showendscreen=true&showsearch=true&showstartscreen=true&tocdoc=float&xmp=sc.xmp&content=http://content.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/IntroVideoV5.mp4&blurover=false" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="base" value="http://content.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/" />
    <iframe type="text/html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden;" src="http://www.screencast.com/users/TheMathsTutor/folders/Default/media/b08282c8-3f04-415c-b6c6-8465331e96ca/embed" height="180" width="320" >
    </iframe>
</object>
```

Comment: Your code was badly formatted, hence why no one answered. I fixed it so it is readable.

Comment: Thanks very much epascarello - I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a div and set a border to 1 pixel.

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:320px;height:180px;">
  <!-- your code -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Turns out Camtasia was putting a thin line on some of the edges when I rendered my video.  It looks fine now that it is disguised with this border.  Thanks for taking the time to reply !